# The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "(null)" could not UPDATE table "[MSDASQL]". Unknown provider error with Pervasive

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, pervasive

The connection is working because I can select the table but when updating getting following error message with Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider reported an unexpected catastrophic failure.
>
> Msg 7343, Level 16, State 4, Line 4
>   The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "(null)" could not UPDATE table "[MSDASQL]". Unknown provider error.

Comment: Can you execute the UPDATE statement through the Pervasive Control Center (or other tool outside of SQL Server)?  Does it throw an error?  If so, what error?

Comment: Yes, I can update through Pervasive Control Center and even with SQL 2008 and Microsoft Access.

Comment: So the error only happens with the linked server and SQL Server 2012? Is the SQL Server 2012 64 bit?  If so, are you using the 64 bit Pervasive ODBC drivers?  What version of Pervasive are you using?

Comment: Yes. I can use select command with out any problems but can't update In SQL 2012. We are using Pervasive 11 and 64 bit Pervasive ODBC driver. Thanks

Comment: @ManjuMehta Did you get some solution? I'm facing similar issue on SQL Server 2016 Enterprise Edition.

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue running an INSERT INTO query from MSSQL/MSSMS to a linked MySQL server. The problem in our case was the MySQL instance required that some fields be provided, even if they were blank. We tested the INSERT INTO via PHPMyAdmin and it was failing on those fields. We added those fields to the INSERT statement with null values and it ran just fine.

If you are having this issue, check your MySQL instance as you may have a required value you are not passing.